# In Django REST Framework, how do you prevent submission of unexpected keys in serializer data?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

For example, say I have:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
```

how do I raise an error when, an unexpected field `height` is submitted:

```
ContactSerializer(data={'name': Jim, 'height': '1 mile'})
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a great question. I initially assumed that the DRF function `serializer.is_valid()` (which validates the data) would throw an exception. I played around with some examples and it does not throw one.

Thinking about this more, I'm not sure you can prevent an unexpected field from being submitted (if you are trying to be mischievous). You can only make sure that the data that is being submitted to an appropriate field, is of a valid type. That said, your serializer will just ignore the `height` field.

Answer (score 0):

DRF does not appear easily allow checking for unspecified field names.  [Marshmellow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) is another more feature rich library for object serialization in Python inspired in part by DRF serializers; it does allow for such checks by using schema level (as opposed to field level) validation ([Marshmellow Schema Validation](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending.html#validating-original-input-data)).

```
class MySchema(Schema):
    foo = fields.Int()
    bar = fields.Int()

    @validates_schema(pass_original=True)
    def check_unknown_fields(self, data, original_data):
        for key in original_data:
            if key not in schema.fields:
                raise ValidationError('Unknown field name {}'.format(key))

schema = MySchema()
result, errors = schema.load({'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'baz': 3})
```